# Do the same in css 3

Tags: css, geometry

Do you know How can I do the same "circle" in css 3?

I tried double div with something like that :

```
border-radius:50%; 
right:0; 
top:50px; 
width:200px; 
height:200px;
```

The main div ( rectangle ) has an overflow set to hidden.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this with only one element and a border + box-shadow alone.

```
div{
    /*unimportant stuff*/
    right:-<x>px;bottom:-<y>px; /*replace x and y accordingly*/
    border-radius:50%;
    background:#bada55;               /*<- inner color*/
    border:30px solid #bada55;        /*<- inset color*/
    box-shadow:-1px -1px 0 1px red,   /*<- inside shadow color*/
          inset 1px 1px 0 1px  white; /*<- outside shadow color*/
}
```

Check out the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nTrCU/3/), obviously ignoring the original colors;)

Comment: Sir, this is almost perfect. But, since the main div has an gradient background, it can't work  I guess. I will try do that in ure way.

Edit : I did that with background:transparent ! Many thanks

Comment: @user2410626 you could as well use rgba colors (e.g. for the "inset" part) and use for example a very transparent black or white to modify the colors. This way the "original" background-color does not matter. See my modified fiddle in the answer.

Answer (score -1):

(Untested) try:

```
border-radius:50%; 
width:200px; 
height:200px;
right: -100px;
bottom: -100px;
```

This should, in theory, place your circle in the desired position.

Comment: This is exactlty what I said, no ? But I need, this "double" circle ( something like in the attached picture )